Why isn't v.je working in my browser after I install Docker
I have installed Docker and initialized it in PowerShell with docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/install vjedev/installer:latest. I ran docker compose up and it downloaded and installed all of the containers that are in vjedev (nginx, database, php, maildev, and mariadb). All of the containers that it loads run in Docker Desktop. I can type 'localhost' into my browser window and get the 'Welcome to nginx!'. I have checked and the v.je files are on my computer. However, if I run v.je in the browser, which should work at this point, it doesn't. I get the message 'This site can't be reached'.
So basically everything has installed in docker correctly and are running. I have checked the ports in windows firewall and they are enabled. Mariadb is running but when I connect to it with MysqlWorkbench, it says that no databases instances were found. I assume it has something to do with windows 11 but am uncertain where to look. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Pleas add other details. Did you run docker-compose up -d ?
